# Си - трассировка программы

Tags: c

Как сделать выполнение программы с трассировкой? Например, в `bash` включить трассировку можно добавив ключ перед выполнением `bash -x script.sh` и видеть весь процесс выполнения скрипта. Как реализовать это при выполнении программ написанных на Си?

Comment: Выполнять пошагово в отладчике :)

Comment: @Harry, Добрый день, вы имеете в виду использовать gdb и выполнять программу пошагово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать команды

- file
- strings
- objdump
- strace (примерно то, что вы хотели)
- ltrace (примерно то, что вы хотели)
- gdb
- sysdig
- ldd
- readelf

Для получения информации о бинарном файле.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` выполняет сценарий строка за строкой, т.е. интерпретирует ваш скрипт. `C` - это компилируемый язык и конечная программа, особенно оптимизированная, кардинально отличается от исходного кода, поэтому это физически невозможно. Единственный близкий вариант - это отладка с помощью дебаггера типа gdb либо модификация программы (логирование).